# Can't find my user info in xmppframework roster list

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I'am using xmppframework doing some stuff, when i trying to get my user info through XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage API it always return nil, and i found my user info is not included in XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject data, any idea?

```
[[XMPPManager xmppRosterStorage] myUserForXMPPStream:[XMPPManager xmppSteam] managedObjectContext:[XMPPManager managedObjectContext_roster]]);
```